# Apply Custom Border Style for Sharepoint 2013 Webparts

Tags: css, sharepoint-2013

I want to give my custom border style to all the Webparts available in sharepoint. So that i have added the following class.

```
.s4-wpcell-plain
{
 border:1px solid #d8d8d8;
}
```

It is applying almost all the webparts. But the problem is it is adding border unnecessarily other places also. Like when search using E-Search page all the results are coming with the borders. It is applying for sharepoint Blog page also.

How can I get rid of those unnecessary borders? or Which CSS I need to apply so that it will only apply for the webparts.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying your border to the following class instead:

```
.ms-webpartzone-cell {
    border: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
}
```

Comment: Actually first I applied in that place only. It didn't give any border in search page. But it is not applying border normally some of the wepart. for example, Documents webpart it is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I was messing with this as well.  The only way it worked for me was to apply  the code to the following

```
    .s4-wpcell {
display: block !important;
-moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gray !important;
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gray !important;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gray !important;}

   .ms-webpart-chrome {
display: block !important;
-moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gray !important;
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gray !important;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gray !important;}

    .s4-wpActive {
display: block !important;
-moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gray !important;
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gray !important;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gray !important;}
```

So this will apply it to all web parts (I was using a wiki page so "hidden" parts also had this applied and suddenly appeared).  To only apply this style to specific web parts add the .MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ# in front of the class.

```
#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2 .s4-wpcell,
#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2 .ms-webpart-chrome,
#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2 .s4-wpActive {
display: block !important;
-moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gray !important;
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gray !important;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gray !important;}
```

Hope this helps.